# Azure KeyVault: set access policy using cli

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

As said in title I'm facing a permission/privilege issue.

I've logged to az-cli using a service principle I created with `Contributor` role.

[image: contributor.snap]

Now, this SP is used in a pipeline, where it needs to edit access policies of a KeyVault for another SP (that has no roles).

I'm using
`az keyvault set-policy -n testserviceprincipal --secret-permissions list --spn <id>`

but i get `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

I tried to add keyvault prmissions but still missing something. [image: keyvault write perm]

Did someone had the same issue and managed to resolve?

I'm somehow sure I'm missing some permissions like user.read cause if I use `--object-id` and the ObjectId of SP all works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like the service principal is missing a MS Graph API application permission or a directory role.

Comment: you was right, after adding the role everything works fine!